# Windows 10 VHD boot entry loop

Tags: boot, infinite-loop

I have added VHD boot entry to my system. My laptop is in boot loop now. How can i delete that entry without access to my main OS?

Help is really appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I’m using UEFI system, it is a Windows 10 Pro laptop. I tried to install second OS (also Win 10) on VHD to have dual boot. However when I added that VHD installation to my boot manager using “bcdboot V:\Windows”, my laptop just boots into that VHD, keeps spinning for 2 minutes and then restarts. The issue is that I forgot to un-set that VHD boot entry as default and set “wait timer” to some seconds. Now the computer doesn’t ask which system to boot and it is repeatedly booting into that VHD OS, which can’t boot for some reason.

Comment: Please [edit] and describe in details what you did, what OS or OSes are installed and how are they booting (UEFI or BIOS).

Comment: I have put in some more information. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Before anything else, please check the UEFI boot order. Chances are the "Windows boot manager" is still there and works to boot the originally installed Windows. If not I'm afraid you'll need to boot from Windows installation media and use the repair tools.

Comment: I am booting to “windows boot manager”, however it automatically tries to boot into the second OS and doesn’t let me choose the primary one. I don’t know how to invoke the screen where you can choose the OS you wish to boot or select recovery mode and such.

Comment: Then you need to repair Windows.

Comment: Can you access boot manager on the main drive from installer? I just need to remove that entry